# How i can create grid on iphone which have multiple coloumns?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gridview

[image]

How i can create grid which can have multiple coloums  in iphone as shown in given image, please suggest me.

Comment: Bear in mind that you may not need the last 2 columns: "VIEW" can be done by tapping on the row, and "DELETE" can be hidden until the User swipes the table row. Therefore you may only really need 4 columns.

Comment: Also, date could be handled as a section in the tableview, since many rows contain the same date, and it would make it easier for your User to see how the items are divided… The following link may be useful: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-sectioned-table-view.html

Comment: If you follow the above suggestions, you need only design a UITableViewCell that contains 3 items: Location, Start and End. If you use a standard UITableViewCell the textLabel could be set to the Location, and the detailTextLabel could combine the START and END (e.g. '12:30pm - 02:30PM')

Answer (score 1):

Apple introduced [`UICollectionView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) in iOS 6 which could be used for this purpose.

Or alternativaly you could use a standard `UITableView` with custom cells which display multiple columns. So you'll have to make a `UITableViewCell` subclass which will contain all the UI needed to display a single row of your table.

Answer (score 0):

As there is now control introduced by Apple in iOS 6, you can use that "UICollectionView" control.

But my suggestion is,

You can go with custom "UITableViewCell".

In that, you can create the tableview cell as per your need, make IBOutlet and IBAction of objects and inside the "CellForRowAtIndexPath", use that all controls and bind methods.

You can easily achieve the grid as per your need. May be you need to design screen Horizontally (Landscape).

Happy Coding!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView) and 'UITableViewCell'

Editing:

1. Create UITableView in particular View
2. delegate and datasource to uitableview
3. take custome uitableviewcell
4. write following delegate and datasource method

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Could you perhaps be a little more specific?